# AM and PM buttons disappear in apk but appear in flutter run , How can I make it look the same in the apk?

Tags: android, flutter

I have an application in flutter and in a time option AM and PM buttons disappear in but appear in flutter run, I have tried with different versions of glade but it is solved, how can I make it appear in the apk:

flutter run image
[flutter run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aoGX.png)
[apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwqsY.jpg)

Comment: You have to edit your question and add your code that you used to show the date time picker

Comment: some suggestions for updating your question:
1. What is Glade? and what are you using it for?.
2. show the code snippet that isn't giving you the result.
3. show us what you'll like to achieve (because you mention buttons dissappeared but I thought you were referring to date time texts not showing . )

Comment: Maybe the difference in 12h and 24h in your settings?